# JQuery Post sends form data and not JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Trying to send json. Here's my function:

```
var object = ... ;

$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<url>',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: object
    });
```

But whenever I check Chrome, it always sends it as query params:

```
Request Payload:
startDate=Wed+Dec+19+2012+19%3A00%3A00+GMT-0500+(EST)&endDate=Thu+Dec+20+2012+19%3A00%3A00+GMT-0500+(EST)&
```

How do I get it to send as JSON?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

With `JSON.stringify(object)`

Sample:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<url>',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(object)
});
```

Note JSON.stringify is not supported in all browsers (http://caniuse.com/#feat=json ), in particular browsers IE7 and lower.

If you need to support this browsers too you can use this Javascript library: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I did something wrong but didn't get an error message. I blame the framework.

Comment: @mick88 np, I will delete my comment then :)

Comment: Stefan, you saved my day

Answer (score 5):

**Stringify** using `JSON.stringify(object)`

Modify the `data` field to:

```
...
data: JSON.stringify(object),
...
```

The way you are doing it, IMO, jQuery sees the parameter as a dictionary (key-value pairs), and constructs a percentile-encoded string from that; and hence you see that output.

Answer (score -2):

I have found it easier to send data in default 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' format with JSON as a field like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<url>',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {json:JSON.stringify(object)}
});
```

On server use the regular method to receive field called `json`.

Just shared to see if this is valid for you.

Comment: Good point! It just depends on how the OP needs/wants it with their server setup