# Cross origin ajax request does not pass Request Payload in JSON format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, cors

I'm writing a chrome extension that makes a service call.

When I make a same origin POST ajax request, my data object gets passed in JSON format:

```
 $.ajax(sameOriginURL, {
    data : {
      "foo1": "bar1",
      "foo2": "bar2"
    },
    dataType: "json",

    headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/json'}
 })
```

In chrome debugger, when I see the post request, request payload shows up as:

```
 {ContentType: "JSON", foo1: "bar1", foo2: "bar2"}
```

But when I do the same with cross origin requst ( insert crossOriginURL in that request in place of sameOriginURL), In chrome debugger,the post request shows up with request payload as this:

```
foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2
```

and service that I'm calling does not like that so it throws a serialization exception. How do pass my request payload as a JSON object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer to this here: [JQuery Post sends form data and not JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956462/jquery-post-sends-form-data-and-not-json)

All I had to do was wrap up my data object with JSON.stringify and it worked !!

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '<url>',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify(object)
});
```