# AJAX form submit to PHP not returning correct data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that I would like to send data from to a `php` script using `AJAX`. However I am running into an issue with actually passing the data across. The `$_POST` array is empty for some reason.

Currently the `HTML` is:

```
<form>
    <label>Email Address:</label>
    <input type='text' name='email' value='jackc@test.com'/>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Check subscription status'/>
</form>
```

The `JQuery` is:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = 'request.php';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                contentType: "json",
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#results').html(data);
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

The `PHP` is:

```
        $emailAddress = $_POST['email'];
        echo "EMAIL: " . $emailAddress;
```

However it's not returning anything. It's blank each time. When I do a console log for `$('form').serialize()` I see `email=jackc%40@test.com` which I would expect to see returned from my `PHP`.

I'd appreciate some help on this. Many thanks.

Comment: Give id to the form element and serialize the data by form id

Comment: Have you tried in php with print_r($_POST) for debug perpose?

Comment: U have used content type as json and just echo the data try to json_encode from php script

Comment: Are you using a php log, maybe you should see what's being outputted to it. Try and find a file on your server called php_error.log and open it in a console. That will tell you what is failing on the server side of the call. Also add this to your php script var_dump($_REQUEST); or var_dump($_POST); more specifically and analyse what's being sent. It sounds like the parameters are not being sent properly. also try replacing data: $('form').serialize(), with data: $(this).serialize(), as it might be looking elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't send json data so you need to remove the "contentType" from the ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this:

> When I do a console log for $('form').serialize() I see
>   email=jackc%40@test.com

You have specified `contentType: "json"`, but you sent something looking like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

You can see here an example: [JQuery Post sends form data and not JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956462/jquery-post-sends-form-data-and-not-json)

Answer (score 0):

test this :

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = 'request.php';
            var $form = $(this);
            var request ={
                email : $form.find("[name=email]").val(),
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: request,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#results').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `dataType: "json",` instead `contentType: "json",` to send data as form data and receive data as json:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = '';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $('#results').html(data);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

If you don't want to receive json data, remove `contentType` at all:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = '';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $('#results').html(data);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add dataType as json instead of contentType and also return json encoded data from server.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form id="test">
    <label>Email Address:</label>
    <input type='text' name='email' value='jackc@test.com'/>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Check subscription status'/>
</form>

<div id="results"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#test').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var formdata = $('#test').serialize();
            var url = 'request.php';

            alert(formdata);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: formdata,
                dataType: "json",
                encode :true,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#results').html(data);
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

**request.php**

```
<?php
$emailAddress = $_POST['email'];
echo json_encode("EMAIL: " . $emailAddress);

?>
```